# Mysql, left join with only first connected record - by a date

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

this question wasnt made at first time in history, still I havent find any useful. Lets suppose the users (A,B,C) can have more tasks (cleaning, maintaining, programing), and tasks can have states (started, paused, paused, done).

```
SELECT username,tasks.id,subject,dateat,state FROM users
LEFT JOIN tasks ON tasks.owner_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN tasks_histories ON tasks_histories.task_id = tasks.id
ORDER BY username ASC, subject asc, dateat desc;
select * from tasks_histories;
```

so there are multiple task states, I only need the first, according the "dateat" - maybe I want the first or last record. I tried to use `GROUP BY username,subject form`, but then it wont watch the dateat ordering.

EDIT:

supposing A has no task, B has two tasks: task1 with one state, task2 with 3 states.

So this returns it:

```
user  taskid  subject  dateat  state
A     null    null     null    null
B     9       task1    2011    5
B     10      task2    null    null
B     8       task3    2011    1
B     8       task3    2012    5
B     8       task3    2013    3
```

but I want it:

```
A     null    null     null    null
B     9       task1    2011    5
B     10      task2    null    null
B     8       task3    2011    1
```

or

```
A     null    null     null    null
B     9       task1    2011    5
B     10      task2    null    null
B     8       task3    2013    3
```

Comment: what is the table that contains `dateat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that column `dateat` is located on table `tasks_histories`, the query below will return results for the latest task based on `dateat`.

```
SELECT  username,
        tasks.id,
        subject,
        dateat,
        STATE
FROM    users
        INNER JOIN tasks
            ON tasks.owner_id = users.id
        INNER JOIN tasks_histories
            ON tasks_histories.task_id = tasks.id
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  task_id, MAX(dateat) max_date
            FROM    tasks_histories
            GROUP   BY task_id
        ) a ON tasks_histories.task_id = a.task_id AND
                tasks_histories.dateat = a.max_date
ORDER   BY username ASC, subject ASC, dateat DESC;
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  x.*, y.*
FROM    users x
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  a.owner_id, a.subject,
                    b.dateat, b.state
            FROM    tasks a
                    INNER JOIN tasks_histories b
                        ON b.task_id = a.ID
                    INNER JOIN 
                    (
                        SELECT  task_id, MAX(dateat) max_date
                        FROM    tasks_histories
                        GROUP   BY task_id
                    ) c ON b.task_id = c.task_id AND
                            b.dateat = c.max_date
        ) y ON x.id = y.owner_id
```

Comment: seems to ok. I forgot to say, I also need those tasks, which has no states (hasnt begun)

Comment: can you give sample records with desired result? how about changing `INNER` into `LEFT` join?

Comment: thx, seems cool. Can you explain what is inside in braketc, INNER JOIN ( ... ) ON ? Or just name this thing, Ive never seen that